# HATEOAS JAX-RS Link-Headers appears multiple times in HEAD

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, hateoas

I'm building a JAX-RS 2.0 API and I am trying to add Link headers.

```
links.add(Link.fromUri(firstUri.build()).rel("first").build());

Link.Builder last = Link.fromUri(lastUri.build()).rel("last");
links.add(last.build());


return Response
        .ok(content)
        .header("X-Total-Count", totalCount)
        .links(links.toArray(new Link[] {}))
        .build();
```

So what I get is this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Total-Count: 224
Link: <entities?limit=15&offset=70>;rel="next"
Link: <entities?limit=15&offset=40>;rel="prev"
Link: <entities?limit=15&offset=0>;rel="first"
Link: <entities?limit=15&offset=210>;rel="last"
Content-Type: application/json
```

But what I want is this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Total-Count: 224
Link: <entities?limit=15&offset=70>;rel="next",<entities?limit=15&offset=40>;rel="prev",<entities?limit=15&offset=0>;rel="first",<entities?limit=15&offset=210>;rel="last"
Content-Type: application/json
```

So, am I doing something wrong or is JAX-RS just not sane?

Comment: Unrelated, but wouldn't it be easier to say `new Link[0]`, instead of `new Link[] {}`, or even better `new Link[links.size()]`?

Comment: Yes sure, thanks.

I'm beginning to think this is an issue with my App Server. JunitTests with jersey do look fine.

Comment: I thought so, but I didn't find any evidence. In all Java jax-rs 2.0 examples, you won't find a curl reply, just a Java interpretation.